# Meteor CordovaLib version

Tags: xcode, cordova, meteor

I need to use latest Cordova lib to build project. However, if I start build it for device, in Xcode under my project root I see CortovaLib.xcodeproj with `VERSION` 3.5.0 (latest on this time is 3.8.0, and what I really need is at least 3.7.0). What I tried is npm install -g cordova and meteor remove/add platform.

Have I possibility to choose cordova lib if I use meteor toolkit, or should I wait for meteor updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the next release of meteor they are upgrading the Cordova CLI dependency from 3.5.1 to 4.2.0. You can read more about the specifics [v.Next](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/419befbf5f42b69095454632618ea2cc64b9a6ef/History.md#meteor-mobile-updates). As far as I know there is not an official release date set.